# VideoView and vitamio for live streaming

Tags: android, media-player, live-streaming, vitamio

I'm using this code to broadcast a live stream on my android app, but unfortunatily, it displays a black screen...

```
    VideoView videoView;
    String LiveUrl = "rtmp://204.107.26.252:8086/live/796.high.stream";

    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.viView);
    videoView.setVideoPath(LiveUrl);
    MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(vidControl);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

and this is my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="io.vov.vitamio.activity.InitActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />

</application>
```

what's wrong guys :( ?
is the LiveUrl should be in the format written above?